# Apache2 service is not starting on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: apache2, ubuntu-14.04

I tried to start apache2 service on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. But it shows that the configtest is failed. I removed it and installed again. But it still isn't working. Here is the problem:

```
root@knight-HP-1000-Notebook-PC:/home/knight# service apache2 restart
* Restarting web server apache2                                         [fail] 
* The apache2 configtest failed.
Output of config test was:
[Sat Jul 29 22:29:48.069226 2017] [so:warn] [pid 8305] AH01574: module 
php5_module is already loaded, skipping
apache2: Syntax error on line 216 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf: Could not open configuration file /etc/apache2/conf-enabled/mysite.conf: No such file or directory
Action 'configtest' failed.
The Apache error log may have more information.
```

Comment: try to disable php... a2dissmode php5_module or something similar..

Comment: I tried  a2dismod php5_module.   But it says,
ERROR: Module php5_module does not exist!

Comment: Can you post a link to your /etc/apache2/apache2.conf, the error message says you have a syntax error on line 216.

Comment: Here it is>>   http://txt.do/do6l4

Comment: `Could not open configuration file /etc/apache2/conf-enabled/mysite.conf: No such file or directory` - does this file exist? What are the permissions on it?